# Why would IE11 drop cookies between requests?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies, httpcookie

I have a C# application that uses cookies to track user authentication (pretty standard stuff). On authentication, a cookie is created with a hash value relating to the database table containing user/authentication information.

In Chrome/Safari/Edge, this works perfectly: in IE11 the cookie is created (I can see it in Developer tools on the login confirmation page), but when clicking an internal link the user is kicked back out to the authentication page (by an ActionFilter, due to no cookie being present) and the cookie is no longer present when viewing the login form. It appears to work correctly when debugging from Visual Studio, and intermittently will even work on the live server when performing the exact same login process.

What could be causing this in IE11, but not Chrome/Edge? (Avoiding IE11 is, unfortunately, not an option). This occurs even with cookies set to Allow for both first and third party, with the site in the Trusted Sites list, and in the compatibility window

Edit: Added code (minus key and value)

Create:

```
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("AppSettings");
cookie.Values["key"] = value;
cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(TMSCookie.CookieValidityDays); // 365
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Retrieve

```
// In MVC Filter
HttpCookie cookie = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Get("AppSettings");
// Otherwise
HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies.Get("AppSettings");
String value = cookie.Values["key"];
```

Comment: Show us the code that sets the cookie.

Comment: Set/retrieve code added

Comment: What is the URL of the login page? And the page that the internal link points to?

Comment: The login page is /Authentication/Login, and the internal link points to /Activity/Index (or possibly just /Activity/, depending on how Razor's HTML.RouteLink resolves, I guess?). Note that this is an MVC project

Comment: On the same domain and scheme? They are both http? Both https?

Comment: Both https, same domain, same deployed project, same Application Pool etc

Comment: Use a http proxy (Fiddler) to see what is going on with your requests and responses.